# Equality on a limit involving solution of heat equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve one exercise on PDEs for a while now and I have everything **except from this equality**. It would be really useful if this were true, but I can't prove it and I think it should be because I am following some hints and I got here. Here $g$ can be smooth, $g(0)=0$ and that's what we know. The step is $$\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int\limits_0^{t-\delta}\dfrac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(t-s)}}g(s) ds+\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int\limits_{t-\delta}^t\dfrac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(t-s)}}g(s) ds$$ $$= g(t) \lim_\limits{x\rightarrow 0^+}\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int\limits_{t-\delta}^t\dfrac{1}{(t-s)^{3/2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4(t-s)}}ds$$

So this is what I think: since we have excluded $t$ from the first integral, we can simply substitute $x$ by $0$ and so the first limit is $0$. Now this is not true for the second limit, as the integral explodes close to $0$. But how can $g$ leave the integral? Is it some argument of continuity? I tried integration by parts but I don't seem to go anywhere.

Thank you very much for your attention!